# Move existing 2D points to newly generated 2D points in an optimized manner

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization

I am trying to solve a problem where I have some existing points (P) that need to move to new location that is generated by some method, say (P`). I want to know if there is a optimization algorithm that finds the best mapping of points.

I tried to map by using the least distance between points choosing the best in a loop but the last ones ended up with worst deal. How can we determine the best mapping?

we are not trying for best time or space complexity since we only have handful of points to work with. Following is what we have till now.

```
getMapping <- function(originalX, originalY, newX, newY)
{
  #Maps original index to new index
  dimemsion <- length(originalX)

  #this matrix will hold distance of each original point from each of the new points
  dist.matrix <- matrix(nrow = dimemsion, ncol= dimemsion)

  #this is a brute force method
  for(i in 1:dimemsion)  # i traverses over original data points
  {
    for(j in 1:dimemsion) # j traverses over new data points
    {
      distance <- sqrt((originalY[i] - newY[j])^2 + (originalX[i] - newX[j])^2)
      dist.matrix[i,j] = distance
    }
  }
  #Best way to find mapping ?????
  ..... Not sure how to do it right now

  return(dist.matrix)
}

#Use Case 1
originalX = c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
originalY = c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)


newX = c( 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
newY = c( 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1)

print(getMapping(originalX, originalY, newX , newY))
```

How can I find best combination from the summationMatrix? Or any algorithm/idea to approach this issue will be appreciated. We are using R as the language here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you better use the `dist` function to produce `summationMatrix` (the name `summationMatrix` is, imho, horrible, I would name it something like dist.matrix or dist.mat).

Second, what you need is called [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I will try it out

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks a lot for quick reply